# Concatenating dataframes adding additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a combined dataframe from a series of 12 individual CSVs (12 months to combine for the year). All the CSVs have the same format and column layout.

When I first ran it, it appeared to work and I was left with a combined dataframe with 6 columns (as expected). Upon looking at it, I found that the header row was applied as actual data in all the files, so I had some bad rows I needed to eliminate. I could manually make these changes but I'm looking to have the code take care of this automatically.

So to that end, I updated the code so it only read in the first CSV with headers and the remaining CSVs without headers and concatenate everything together. This appears to work ***BUT*** I end up with 12 columns instead of 6 with the first 6 columns having NaNs for the first CSV and the last 6 columns having NaNs for the other 11 CSVs, which is obviously NOT what I want (see image below).

The code is similar, I just use the `header=None` parameter in `pd.read_csv()` for the 11 CSVs after the first (and I don't use that parameter for the first CSV). Can anyone give me a hint as to why I'm getting 12 columns (with the data placement as described) when I run this code? The layout of the CSV file is shown below.

Appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Need to include the header row only for the first csv (otherwise header row will be included
# for each read csv, which places improperly formatted rows into the combined dataframe).
totrows = 0

# Get list of csv files to read.
files = os.listdir('c:/data/datasets')

# Read the first csv file, including the header row.
dfSD = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + files[0], skip_blank_lines=True)

# Now read the remaining csv files (without header row) and concatenate their values
# into our full Sales Data dataframe.
for file in files[1:]:
    df = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + file, skip_blank_lines=True, header=None)
    dfSD = pd.concat([dfSD, df])
    totrows += df.shape[0]
    print(file + " == " + str(df.shape[0]) + " rows")               

print()
print("TOTAL ROWS = " + str(totrows + pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + files[0]).shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

totrows = 0

files = os.listdir('c:/data/datasets')

dfSD = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + files[0], skip_blank_lines=True)

columns = []
dfSD = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + file, skip_blank_lines=True)
    if not columns:
        columns = df.columns
    df.columns = columns

    dfSD.append(df)

    totrows += df.shape[0]
    print(file + " == " + str(df.shape[0]) + " rows")               

dfSD = pd.concat(dfSD, axis = 0)

dfSD = dfSD.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Another possibility is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Need to include the header row only for the first csv (otherwise header row will be included
# for each read csv, which places improperly formatted rows into the combined dataframe).
totrows = 0

# Get list of csv files to read.
files = os.listdir('c:/data/datasets')

# Read the first csv file, including the header row.
dfSD = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + files[0], skip_blank_lines=True)
df_comb = [dfSD]
# Now read the remaining csv files (without header row) and concatenate their values
# into our full Sales Data dataframe.
for file in files[1:]:
    df = pd.read_csv('c:/data/datasets/' + file, skip_blank_lines=True, header=None)

    df.columns = dfSD.columns
    df_comb.append(df)
    totrows += df.shape[0]
    print(file + " == " + str(df.shape[0]) + " rows")

dfSD = pd.concat([df_comb], axis = 0).reset_index(drop = True)
```